# Как удалить или добавить данные с помошью KENDOGRID + Angular js + web api?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, grid, kendo

как мне удалить елемент из бд с помошью Kendo grid ?

Мой контроллер:

```
namespace Simple.Controllers
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Models;

    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class CarsController :Controller
    {
        private readonly ICarRepository _cars;

        public CarsController(ICarRepository repository)
        {
           this._cars = repository;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Car> Get() => _cars.GetCars;

        // GET api/cars/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            var car = this._cars.GetCar(id);
            if (car == null)
                return NotFound();
            return new ObjectResult(car);
        }

        // POST api/cars
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Car car)
        {
            if (car == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            this._cars.Add(car);
            return Ok(car);
        }

        // PUT api/cars/
        [HttpPut]
        public IActionResult Put([FromBody]Car car)
        {
            if (car == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            this._cars.Update(car);
            return Ok(car);
        }

        // DELETE api/cars/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var car = this._cars.GetCar(id);
            if (car == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            this._cars.Remove(car.Id);
            return Ok(car);
        }
    }
}
```

Код на angular:

```
    angular.module("KendoDemos", ["kendo.directives"])
    .controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.mainGridOptions = {
                        dataSource: {
                            transport: {
                                read: {
                                    url: "/api/cars"
                                },
                                update: {
                                    url: "api/cars/",
                                    type: "PUT"
                                },
                                create: {
                                    url: "api/cars",
                                    type: "POST"
                                },
                                destroy: {
                                    url: "api/cars/${id}" ,
                                    type: "DELETE"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                            return {
                                models: kendo.stringify(options.models)
                            };
                        }
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "id",
                        fields: {
                            Name: { type: "string" },
                            Color: { type: "string" }
                        }
                    }
                },
                batch: false,
                pageSize: 10,
                serverPaging: true,
                serverSorting: true
            },
            editable: "inline",
            toolbar: ["create"],
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            resizeable: true,
            dataBound: function () {
                this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    field: "name",
                    title: "Name",
                    width: "120px"
                }, {
                    field: "color",
                    title: "Color",
                    width: "120px"
                },
                {
                    command: ["edit",
                        {
                            name: "destroy",
                            text: "remove",
                            width: "120px"
                        }
                    ],
                }
                        ],
                        selectable: "row",
                        change: function () {
                            var selectedRows = this.select();
                           this.data = this.dataItem(selectedRows[0]);
                        }
        };
    })
```